# Use cursor loader for multiple data sources

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I have code that fetches contact information from Android using the contact name as the selection. However, the datasource (which I guess would be ContactsContract.Contacts) does not have everything I need about the contact. I see that contact information is divided between several tables (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone, etc). I have also notices that all of these sources have access to a LOOKUP_KEY field. It uniquely identifies a contact. I want to know if there is a way to perform a join on these datasources using the LOOKUP_KEY.

Below, I currently setup the projection and selection for a single datasource and query it asynchronously using a cursor loader. Is there a way to search multiple datasources at once using the LOOKUP_KEY?

```
private static final String[] CONTACT_PROJECTION = {
        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
};

private static final String CONTACT_SELECTION = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY
        + " LIKE ?";

public static Loader<Cursor> getContactLoader(Context applicationContext, String searchString) {
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[1];
    selectionArgs[0] = "%" + searchString + "%";
    return new CursorLoader(
            applicationContext,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            CONTACT_PROJECTION,
            CONTACT_SELECTION,
            selectionArgs,
            null
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All info on all contacts is grouped in alias tables, which are actually stored in a single big table called [`Data`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html), so you can simply query that table for all info related to a specific contact (you can use `CONTACT_ID`, no need to mess with the more problematic `LOOKUP_URI`), like so:

```
public void getContactInfo(long contactId) {

    Uri uri = Data.CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = new String[]{
            Data.CONTACT_ID,
            Data.DISPLAY_NAME,
            Data.MIMETYPE,
            Data.DATA1}; // you can get additional info if needed in Data.DATA2, DATA3, etc.

    // get all relevant info about the contact
    String selection = Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + " IN (?,?,?,?)"; // you can add more question marks if you need more MIMETYPES
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(contactId), Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String name = cursor.getString(1);
        String mimetype = cursor.getString(2);
        String data = cursor.getString(3);

        // use the mimetype to figure out what kind of info is in this row

        Log.i("Contact Info", contactId + "=> " + name + " - " + mimetype + ": " + data);
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```